# iOS - TapGestureRecognizer - Tap is applicable for the whole screen not for a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my app, I have an image and a `UITextView`.
I have created a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for both the views but the issue is that wherever I click on the screen, only the method associated with the `UITextView` gets executed.
Even if I click on the image, only the `UITapGestureRecognizer` method associated with the `UITextView` gets executed.

Following is the code I've implemented:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizerImage = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                            action:@selector(handleTapFromImage:)];
[infobutton addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerImage];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerImage];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                       action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
[messageOne addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

//The following are the methods associated
- (void) handleTapFrom: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //Code to handle the gesture
    NSLog(@"I am in handleTapFrom method");
}

- (void) handleTapFromImage: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //Code to handle the gesture
    NSLog(@"I am in handleTapFrom Image method");
    [self.view makeToast:@"Your verification code does not match. Re-enter your verification code"];
}
```

I am sure I am missing something here.
The association in storyboard is correct to my knowledge.

Please correct me where I am going wrong

Thanks for your time

Comment: did you set imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting both the Tap Gesture Objects on `[self view]` object.
Also, the `UIImageView` object, lets call it `imageObj`, should have `userInteractionEnabled = YES`.

instead of:

```
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerImage];
```

you should do:

```
[imageObj setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageObj addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerImage];
```

---

You generally use `-addGestureRecognizer:` on the object you want your gesture object to work on.
Say you have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` object called `myTapGesture`.

Then, to make it work...

1. on a `UILabel *lblSomeObj` it will be:

   - `[lblSomeObj addGestureRecognizer:myTapGesture];`
2. on a `UIView *vwSomeObj` it will be:

   - `[vwSomeObj addGestureRecognizer:myTapGesture];`
3. etc...

Answer (score 3):

You should not add gesture on self.view.

It should get added on the view for which you want to identify tap event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include this piece of code:-

```
 [tapGestureRecognizerImage requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapGestureRecognizer]; 
[imageObj addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the gesture in the respective views and not in self.view.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizerImage = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFromImage:)];

[infobutton addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerImage];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
[messageOne addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add gesture on UIImageView object and make sure that image view `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `YES`

```
imageObj.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageObj addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerImage];
```